# Git SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect

Tags: git, ssl, github, windows-10, github-desktop

I am new to git bash on windows10, and github Desktop. The problem is that I cannot do any actions like clone from or push to github. The first error I had is

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

There are lots of solutions available on the Internet, but none of them works. I tried the following:

1. `git config --global http.sslbackend schannel`: This gives me another error

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx.git/': schannel: SNI or certificate check failed: SEC_E_WRONG_PRINCIPAL (0x80090322) - The target principal name is incorrect.
```

and **I can't find any solutions to this error**.

2. Add certificate from github and `git config --global http.sslCAinfo /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`
3. Reinstall Git bash, git Desktop, restart computer.

I really don't want to disable my SSL verification. Is there any other way to solve my problem? Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Are you using a proxy or TLS middlebox, or an antivirus or firewall other than the default?  If so, does disabling it (or, in the case of non-default antivirus or firewall, completely uninstalling and rebooting) fix the problem?  Also, is your OS up to date?

Comment: @bk2204 I am not using a proxy, but a firewall may be applied. I do think that my OS is up to date

Comment: If you're using an antivirus or firewall other than Windows Defender and Windows Firewall, that's likely your problem.  Many of those programs try to intercept your TLS traffic, which is bad for security and also breaks software like Git.